# Events added with addEvent, don't take the color of their Resource

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

I'm using FullCalendar V5, I have a sidebar showing the resources I'm showing on the calendar.
At the Calendar's first load, I'm adding several resources and their related events, everything works perfectly, I can see the events and the have the color of their resource.

Then, by clicking on a resource on the sidebar, I can remove the resource and the related events or in the opposite I can add a resource and the related events. I'm adding dynamically the resource and the events by using respectively addResource and addEvent methods.
Here is my problem, the resource and the events are well added but the events remain blue, they don't take the resource's color even if the resourceId property of the event is the id of the resource... ( screenshots below ).

I tried the same kind of process by using some eventSource objects instead of simple events and I don't know why it's working, the newly added events have the right color... but I don't want to use this solution, just because I don't know how to move an event from one eventSource to an other...

Any idea why addEvent doesn't seems to link properly events and resources ?

Here are the two functions for removing and adding one resource and its events :

```
function FMP_RemoveResource(id){
    var events = calendar.getResourceById(id).getEvents();
    events.forEach( event => {
                                                 event.remove();
                               }
    );

    calendar.getResourceById(id).remove();
};


function FMP_AddEvent(strResource,strEvents){
    var resource = JSON.parse(strResource),
          events = JSON.parse(strEvents);

     calendar.addResource( resource );

     events.forEach( event => {
                                                  calendar.addEvent(event);
                                }

     );
};
```

and here is a sample of strResource and strEvents :

strResource

```
{
    "eventColor" : "#FFA500",
    "id" : "EFC9E5DC-408E-4B54-81D4-BA46CF42E0F5",
    "title" : "Calendrier 2"
}
```

strEvents

```
[
    { 
        "end":"2020-08-19 16:00:00",
        "extendedProps":
        {
            "timeBackgroundColor":""
        },
        "id":"CAD946CD-6491-4F5E-AC33-D668A8D54D02",
        "resourceId":"EFC9E5DC-408E-4B54-81D4-BA46CF42E0F5",
        "start":"2020-08-19 10:45:00",
        "title":"Nouvel événement"
    },
    {
        "end":"2020-08-20 13:45:00",
        "extendedProps":
        {
            "timeBackgroundColor":""
        },
        "id":"9ABB7423-74B3-4A16-B098-CB04421386D8",
        "resourceId":"EFC9E5DC-408E-4B54-81D4-BA46CF42E0F5",
        "start":"2020-08-20 11:30:00",
        "title":"Nouvel événement"
    }
]
```

[image: First step : Calendar first load]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "I don't know how to move an event from one eventSource to an other"...why would you need to, exactly? I couldn't understand why that's a limitation.

Comment: My idea was to give the same Id to both the resource and the eventSource, the eventSource contains all the events related to the resource. I'm using the Vertical Resource View, when I'm dragging and dropping an event to one resource to an other, I change dynamically the resource of the event but not the eventSource...

Comment: so when I'm moving an event and after this I remove the resource by using my side bar, the function is removing the resource and the eventSource that contains the previously moved event and the event is disappearing... that's why I wanted to change the eventSource, to prevent the event to be removed, but I'm gonna check my code again just in case I miss something

Comment: Ok I see. So 1) I can't reproduce your problem with the colour, using the data and code provided - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/GRZNQQp . And 2) if you're only using resource-aware views, then to hide a resource there's no requirement to also remove the events - see this demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/zYqoRRJ . Removing the resource itself is sufficient, since an event cannot be shown on a resource-aware view if either a) the resource it's associated with doesn't exist, or b) it's not associated with any resource at all. That might help with your event source problem I'd guess.

Comment: P.S. I haven't tried it but I'd expect you should be able to use the [setProp](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Event-setProp) method to change the `source` property of an event...it's possibly worth attempting if you feel you still need it.

Comment: 1) and 2) Sorry I should give you more information, it's totally true with Resource views it's enough to remove the resource but I'm just using the Vertical Resource Day View, for the week and the month I'm using the normal timeGridWeek and timeGridMonth, in this case, removing only the resource will just affect the events color ! and you should be able to reproduce the problem 1) if the view is set to timeGridWeek... sorry my mistake !

Comment: In fact I tried to use setProp method too change the source, but it doesn't seems to work... I'll try again and let you know

Comment: Yes I can reproduce it with timeGridWeek - https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/bGpBvYM . I don't know the internals but I'd guess that it isn't supposed to work like that. I don't know if there anything we can do about it realistically - I suggest raising a bug with the fullCalendar team, there are instructions here: https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs - since v5 is relatively new there are probably some glitches like this still to be ironed out I'd guess.

Comment: Yes I think so... Especially because it's working well by using eventSources so I can't figure why the behavior should be different using simple events... thanks a lot for your help I will send everything to the team and we'll see !